# Is there a way to exclude certain values/variables from a wildcard in a for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

```
for /d %%A IN (u:\mainfolder\*) DO if not exist "%%A\%var1%" mkdir "%%A\subfolder"
```

I want to exclude certain folders in the directory u:\mainfolder\ so that mkdir executes on all but a few of the folders there. Is there a way to exclude certain folders given the use of the wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 2 or 3 to exclude you can do something like this.

```
for /d %%A IN (u:\mainfolder\*) DO if /i not "%%A"=="u:\mainfolder\Name1ToExclude" if /i not "%%A"=="u:\mainfolder\Name2ToExclude" if not exist "%%A\%var1%" mkdir "%%A\subfolder"
```

Otherwise if you have more, you probably want to use a table of names to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

The command **FOR** does not support an exclude option.

But the task can be achieved using the commands **DIR** and **FINDSTR** executed by **FOR**.

```
@echo off
set "MainFolder=U:\mainfolder"
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir "%MainFolder%\*" /AD /B ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /V /X /C:"Exclude Folder 1" /C:ExcludeFolder2 /C:FolderToExclude3 2^>nul') do if not exist "%MainFolder%\%%A\%var1%" mkdir "%MainFolder%\%%A\subfolder"
set "MainFolder="
```

The command **DIR** is executed to output only directories in directory specified with environment variable `MainFolder` because of the options `/AD` (attribute directory) and `/B` (bare format). The directory names are output by **DIR** without path, just the directory names.

The output of **DIR** is piped as input to **FINDSTR** using redirection operator `|`.

**FINDSTR** searches in all lines for one of the strings specified with option `/C` as literal string because of option `/L` not enclosed in double quotes or enclosed in double quotes because of directory name contains a space character or one of these characters: `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``

The search is case-insensitive because of option `/I`.

A match is only positive if the enter line matches completely with a search string because of `/X` which means the entire directory name must match completely with one of the search strings.

The option `/V` results in an inverted output by **FINDSTR**. Instead of printing the lines matching with one of the search strings, it prints the lines (= directory names) not matching with any of the search strings.

The filtered directory names without path are processed line by line by **FOR**.

The redirection operators `|` and `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` in the finally executed command line:

```
dir "U:\mainfolder\*" /AD /B | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L /V /X /C:"Exclude Folder 1" /C:ExcludeFolder2 /C:FolderToExclude3 2>nul
```

This command line is executed by **FOR** with using a separate command process started in the background. The redirection operators `|` and `>` must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal characters on parsing the entire **FOR** command line by Windows command interpreter before executing command **FOR** with the rest of the line.

On a longer list of directories to exclude I suggest to write the directory names into a plain text file and use option `/G:` of **FINDSTR** instead of specifying them all with `/C:` on command line.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer. Here's my end result:

for /d %%A IN (u:\"folder1\*") DO findstr "%%~nA" "exclusions.txt">nul||if not exist "%%A\%yy%" mkdir "%%A\%yy%"

Comment: @kudika Your solution is working but a bit inefficient as __FINDSTR__ is executed on each directory name individually instead of running it only once on list of directories to work as filter.